# How to set UITabBarItem widths evenly to take up all of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I would like the tab bar items in my app to evenly take up all of the tab bar whether in portrait or landscape.  I have five tabs on my tab bar.  The code below does not accomplish this.  What am I doing wrong?  I noticed that the screenSize.size.height actually references the width and I am not sure why that is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;

CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

float width;

if (self.isShowingLandscapeView){
    width  = screenSize.size.height/5;
}
else {
    width  = (screenSize.size.width/5);
}

[tabBar setItemWidth:width];
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything, the tab bar items should automatically size to equal widths.

Comment: Right, but I want the 5 tab bar items to evenly take up the whole Tab Bar.  By default, that doesn't happen.

Comment: Really? Can you attach a screenshot? I must be misunderstanding what you are asking.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm talking about from another thread: ![Tab Bar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xKyJ.png)

Comment: In your sample code, why do you divide the screen HEIGHT by 5 when in landscape? Does the screen height value not change when you rotate the device? Did you try dividing by width in both orientations?

Comment: For some reason the screenSize.size.height property always gives me the value for height regardless of orientation.  I have no idea why.  For example, on my ipad which is 1024 x 768.  the screenSize.size.height property value is 1024 when I expect it to be 768.

Answer (score 2):

In your `viewDidLoad()`, set

> tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill

Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 you can also enter the following in `viewDidLoad` method

`tabBar.alignment = .justified`

Answer (score 0):

In the tab bar attribute inspector in your story board file. Change the item positioning property to centered. Two fields additional fields item width and item spacing will appear. next to item spacing select custom and enter a value that satisfies your spacing requirement. Hope that helps.
[image]