# How to spacing tab bar items equally in tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 3 tab bar items, I want them to show like this in tab bar:

```
|                  |

|    1    2    3   |

|                  |
```

I see this property in InterfaceBuilder:

[image]

I have tried all cases, but it doesn't work, it shows something like this:

```
|                  |

|      1  2  3     |

|                  |
```

Comment: use flexible space in between your bar items like flexiblespace-item1-flexiblespace-item2-flexiblespace-item3-flexiblespace

Comment: Answered this question in another post. see solution here.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44552862/2479910)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simplest solution:

If you have a sub TabBarController, add this code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it works for me.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 6
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, here is a universal solution, without any hard coded values.

In the `viewDidLoad()` of your `UITabBarController`, set

> tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill

Comment: Works for me. You can either create a new class or select this option in the Interface Builder

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for Objective-C.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tabBar setItemPositioning:UITabBarItemPositioningFill];
}
```

You can also set the value in the Storyboard on the Tab Bar

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer requires tabBar.itemPositioning to be set in order for it to work. If the above answer does not work, try setting it to .centered. Thereafter, you should be able to programmatically set the item spacing.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
    self.tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 6
}
```